# Elimination vs reduction reactions - how to tell

Tags: organic-chemistry, redox, organic-reduction, elimination

Here are two compounds:

Compound H:

[image]

and compound I:

[image]

Compound H reactions with the reagent shown below to form compound I and two other products.

How would you clarify this reaction? I thought it was a reduction, because we are losing the oxygen bonded on the left hand side of the molecule. The actual answer is **elimination** Any advice for tell-tale signs for this type of reaction, and why my answer was wrong?

[image]

Comment: The oxygen-bonded group isn't the only thing you're losing. I assume you know what these structures mean -- draw in all the hydrogens explicitly (OK, skip those on the ring) and count them carefully.

Comment: If the phosphate group were a bromine, would you even ask the question?

Comment: @orthocresol - I'm not sure what you're getting at, unfortunately, I counted the Hs up but how does that help? What tells you that this is an elimination reaction?

Comment: You're losing an oxygen-based group (the phosphate), yes, but you're also losing a hydrogen.

Comment: By the way - this isn't a criticism of you, but rather I feel I should point it out, as you seem to be taught otherwise - "oxidation/reduction" and "addition/elimination" are entirely orthogonal concepts to one another. An elimination reaction can be oxidative, reductive, or indeed redox-neutral. The reaction you have here falls into this last category: it is an elimination (you are losing groups across a double bond), but there is no redox going on, as the overall oxidation state is preserved.

Comment: It is somewhat akin to size and colour. Just because a suitcase big, doesn't mean it can't also be brown. Classifying reactions into "elimination" and "reduction" is like classifying suitcases into "big" and "brown". Most of the time, you'll be OK, but when you get a big brown suitcase this classification falls apart. Likewise, classifying this reaction is fine, but if and when you get shown a reductive elimination, it won't fit into *either* elimination *or* reduction: it'll be both.